# Problems with NonlinearModelFit: "..is not a real number at "

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

I am a newcomer to Mathematica. Basically I just want to fit the data shown below (`ArrayFVel`). Unfortunately, the model contains rather complicated integral that cannot be solved analytically, but it can be solved numerically. Function `V` is the domain of function `well`. I get the following error:

[image]

```
ArrayFVel = 
  {{1.04636, 17.0544}, {1.69469, 79.1147}, {2.17592, 129.16}, {2.17978, 173.519}};

L = 4.0*^-3;
kT = 1.38*^-5*300;
diff = 30.0;

f[x_?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ, G_?NumericQ] := G*Exp[A (1 - 1/(1 - x^2))]; 
g[x_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ] := 2 ((x + L/2)/(L/2*2))^(-(Log[2]/Log[1/2 + m/2])) - 1;
well[x_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ, G_?NumericQ] := f[g[x, m], A, G];

V[x_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ, G_?NumericQ] := 
  Piecewise[
    {{well[x, m, A, G], 
       x >= -L/2 && x <= L/2 && NumericQ @ m && NumericQ @ A && NumericQ @ G}, 
     {well[x - L, m, A, G], 
       x > L/2 && x <= L/2 + L && NumericQ @ m && NumericQ @ A && NumericQ @ G}}]&;

n[m_?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ, G_?NumericQ, F_?NumericQ] = 
  NIntegrate[
    Exp[V[NumericQ[y], m, A, G] - F*NumericQ[y]/kT]*
      Exp[F*NumericQ[x]/kT - V[NumericQ[x], m, A, G]] // 
        Evaluate, {x, -L/2, L/2}, 
    {y, x, x + L}];

model[m_?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ, G_?NumericQ, F_?NumericQ] = 
  Abs[L*diff/n[m, A, G, F]*(1 - Exp[-F*L/kT])];

fit = 
  NonlinearModelFit[
    ArrayFVel, 
    {model[m, A, G][F], -1 <= m <= 0, 0 <= A <= 32, -14 <= G <= 0}, 
    {{m}, {A}, {G}}, 
    F]
```

Comment: Probably `model[m, A, G, F]` instead of `model[m, A, G][F]`?

Comment: The `&` at the end of the definition of `V` is extremely suspect. `V` is not a pure function.

Comment: Since `NumericQ[y]` returns a non-numeric Boolean (`True` or`False`) using it as a numeric quantity as you do in the definition of `n` is also highly suspect. Did you actually test each of your defined functions  as you wrote them and before going on to the next?

Comment: 3 parameters and an error variance with just 4 data points. You sure are optimistic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because fitting 3 parameters plus an error variance with just 4 data points is ridiculous.

Comment: About the small dataset, it may well be a minimum working example. The only reason I see to close this is that the problem seems to be a trivial syntax error. There is no need to punish the OP with downvotes.

Comment: @rhermans If the OP stated that this is an MWE, then I completely agree with you. But the statement "I just want to fit the data shown below" does not suggest that to me.  If the OP says it's an MWE, then I'll remove my comments and downvote.  If someone was attempting to do something silly in physics or engineering even though *Mathematica* code could be made to obtain a result, I would certainly hope that a subject-matter expert would express concern or even dismay.  (And my use of "ridiculous" is probably better replaced with the word "inappropriate".)

Comment: @JimB, yes, *"ridiculous"* was a bit strong and unnecessary. Also downvoting the mathematical skills of the person doesn't make sense. The question had context, an example of the error, mostly reasonable mathematica code in formatted form (with mistakes). Conceding there are mathematical and syntax misunderstanding, the question showed some diligence was not a bad question and I see no point on ridiculing or downvoting the OP. The question is now *on hold* anyhow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either

```
model[m_?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ, G_?NumericQ, F_?NumericQ] = 
  Abs[
   L*diff/n[m, A, G, F]*(1 - Exp[-F*L/kT])
   ];

fit = Normal@NonlinearModelFit[
    ArrayFVel
    , {model[m, A, G, F], -1 <= m <= 0, 0 <= A <= 32, -14 <= G <= 0}
    , {{m}, {A}, {G}}
    , F
    ];
```

Or

```
model[m_?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ, G_?NumericQ][F_?NumericQ] = 
  Abs[
   L*diff/n[m, A, G, F]*(1 - Exp[-F*L/kT])
   ];

fit = Normal@NonlinearModelFit[
   ArrayFVel
   , {model[m, A, G][F], -1 <= m <= 0, 0 <= A <= 32, -14 <= G <= 0}
   , {{m}, {A}, {G}}
   , F
   ];
```

Buth not mixed.

```
Plot[
 fit
 , {F, 0, 10}
 , PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image]